Give access to a Big Query view to Google Sheets add-on users
I'd like to give my Google Sheets add-on users the ability to view Big Query data in a connnected sheet.
The perfect flow would be:
1- They push the button to display their data (from the sidebar)
2- A new connected sheet is created with a view containing only their data (filtered by their id)
Constraints:

Each user should have their own view (with their own data).
I don't want the data to be pushed to their instance of Big Query. On the contrary, I'd like to keep the data stored in my project.

The scope of the question is connected Sheets. I would like to avoid printing a basic Google Sheets table.
Looking forward to your ideas to achieve this

Hi @Matt Pi, Could you check this use Delegated Access with Connected Sheets ?, Let me know if this helps you or not.

Thanks for the answer. According to the doc, Delegated Access can't be turned on through Apps Script and Sheets API

Hi @Matt Pi, I have posted the above comment as answer, if it addressed your question, do consider accepting and upvoting it as per Stack Overflow guidelines, helping more Stack contributors with their research. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

I would need to provide the feature in an add-on (a Google Sheets Editor add-on). Because delegated access doesn't seem to be operated programmatically, it doesn't solve my problem

Hi @Matt Pi, I have updated the answer, please have a look on it.

As mentioned in this documentation, the delegated Access can't be turned on through Apps Script and Sheets API. You need to contact your admin to enable Delegated Access from the admin console. You can also check in the above documentation regarding the uses of delegated access.
If your issue is still unresolved, I would suggest you to create a new GCP support case if you have a support plan. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.
